# Cordova - Checking WIFI connection to internet

Tags: android, ios, cordova, android-wifi, smartphone

I use Cordova to develop a smartphone application.

In this app, I need to check the internet connection before send request to a server.

In order to do that I use the Cordova Connection API, but in the case that the device is connected to a WIFI network with no Internet connection, this API say that we have WIFI connection,

is there any way to check if internet is available on the WIFI network ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send an Dummy ajax request before you send the actual request, If you get and Error Code as '0' it means there is no internet connectivity.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'TestUrl',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
                // Go ahead with you request
    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
        if (x.status == 0) {
            alert("Please connect to the internet");
        }
       else{
           alert("Other Error Occured")
        }
    }
});
```

Secondly you can also make you of HTML 5 navigator

```
var condition = navigator.onLine ? "ONLINE" : "OFFLINE";
```

Comment: I tried your HTML5 solution, but it doesn't work and show ONLINE when my WIFI doesn't provide Internet connection

Comment: Your first solution work, but I actually use it and want to check the connection before send an AJAX Request, in order to avoid the long wait time before AJAX timeout.

Comment: var condition = navigator.onLine ? "ONLINE" : "OFFLINE"; this will give status online even if there is no wifi but your wifi is on

Comment: @divesh Try to send an AJAX request and treat the error implies that the user wait the AJAX request to timeout. I wanna know if there is a faster solution. Seems like no

Comment: This works for non-wifi (3g or 4g) as well, thus this answer doesn't answer the question for Wifi only.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used cordova much, but I think it cannot recognise if you have internet access, it just recognises if you are connected to a network.

You can do a work-around: try to send your request and catch the error you get when it fails, from there you can tell the user that he doesn't have internet access.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information` to add the `Connection` feature. [These are the `Connection` docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html).

That plugin will give access to `window.Connection`.

Then you can do something like:

```
if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
    alert("you're going to need more internet, brah");
}
```

You'll also get access to other states, such as `CELL_2G`,`CELL_3G`, `WIFI`, etc...