# Phonegap online eventlistener not responding to Internet Connection

Tags: ios, cordova

I want to detect if the device is connected to Internet but unfortunately I am unable to do so. While going through the Phone Gap Documentation about Events [online](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_events_events.md.html#online) it said that this event will respond to Internet Connection but unfortunately it only responds if you are connected to a network (wifi for example) or not. I tested it by keeping myself connected to the network and unplugging Internet cable. So at this instance I had Network connectivity but no Internet connectivity, hence the event should have got triggered but it didnt. Later when I switched wifi off (no Network Connectivity) the event triggered immediately.

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
```

The above eventlistener is in onDeviceReady() function.

```
function onOffline() {
    alert("You are now offline");
}
function onOnline() {
    alert("You are now online");
}
```

Any suggestions on how to detect Internet connectivity or what I might be doing wrong here?

I am using PhoneGap 2.9.1

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540150/cordova-checking-wifi-connection-to-internet/20540481#20540481)

Comment: I am not sure if you can send ajax call to an external link or can you?

Comment: Yes you can U need to enable cors

Comment: enable what? I am sorry I didn't quite get what you meant there

Comment: Secondly ajax call is a little ineffective method though at least it will work if external link can be parsed in the ajax call. Isn't there any more effective method to perform the same task?